# How to import JSON file with different values into a SQL table?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I got a JSON file being generated each day. It could have different structure depends on the source data (attributes could be more or less in each JSON file).  For example:
File 1 has attributes: productCode, productType, sellerName, sellerCountry
File 2 has all above attributes plus sellerState
next file could have more or less attributes than file 2

How could I flatten this kind of JSON file into a SQL table dynamically?

File1:

```
[
  {
    "productCode": "00001",
    "productType": "Food",
    "sellerDetails": [
      {
        "sellerName": "Cosco",
        "sellerCountry": "UK"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "productCode": "00002",
    "productType": "Clothing"
  }
]
```

File2:

```
[
  {
    "productCode": "00001",
    "productType": "Food",
    "sellerDetails": [
      {
        "sellerName": "Cosco",
        "sellerCountry": "UK"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "productCode": "00002",
    "productType": "Clothing"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "00003",
    "productType": "Toy",
    "sellerDetails": [
      {
        "sellerName": "Cosco",
        "sellerCountry": "AUS",
        "sellerState": "VIC"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: There is no automatic normalization process (excepting ChatGPT basically doing your job for you). You'll need to figure it out based on your knowledge of the problem-domain.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388759/1690217)

Comment: What happens if property doesnt exist in the table. How dynamic is your dynamic

Comment: It can be helpful to also include a manual constructed example of the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do this dynamically using dynamic SQL generation, but in most cases that is not necessary.

In JSON files it is common to exclude properties for individual entities if their value is `null`. This means that although it looks like the output is *dynamic* systems that generate these files will usually conform to a standard schema. In this case there is a maximal structure that is possible but if you do not know this schema you can determine it from comparing files.

Once you have a fixed schema, we can read all files according to that schema and the missing properties will be imported with a `null` value.

A complicating factor in this input is that the `sellerDetails` is a nested array, in SQL this is a new dimension or *table*, so we need to join on the results of extracting the root element properties which will flatten the data.

> This is described in [How to use OPENJSON on multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58771778/1690217)

Let us therefore define the maximal schema assuming that `sellerDetails` has the 3 properties: `sellerName`, `sellerCountry`, `sellerState`. If you identify more fields, add them to the `WITH` declaration.

This fiddle demonstrates a solution in MS SQL Server: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7d5fd/2

> I have unioned the two inputs into the same resultset so you can compare the output

```
SELECT DISTINCT product.ProductCode, product.productType, seller.*
FROM
(
  SELECT @json1 as json
  UNION 
  SELECT @json2
) input
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (json)
WITH (
    productCode varchar(10), 
    productType varchar(50), 
    sellerDetails NVARCHAR(MAX) as JSON
) product
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (product.sellerDetails) 
WITH (
  sellerName varchar(50),
  sellerCountry varchar(50),
  sellerState varchar(50)
) seller
```

| ProductCode | productType | sellerName | sellerCountry | sellerState |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | Food | Cosco | UK | NULL |
| 00002 | Clothing | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 00003 | Toy | Cosco | AUS | VIC |

> Notice the code ignores the missing `sellerState` from the first file and injects `NULL`

### UPDATE:

Thank you to [@Charlieface](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14868997/charlieface) for pointing out that we should consider using `OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (product.sellerDetails)` for nested `OPENJSON` calls. `CROSS APPLY` behaves like an `INNER JOIN`, so using cross apply here results in fintering out `product` records that did not have *any* `sellerDetails` records, like 'Clothing' in this example.

`DISTINCT` is also added to this query to remove the duplicate entries, product `00002 Clothing` for instance appears in both files.

---

These are the variable declarations:

```
DECLARE @json1 varchar(max) = '[
  {
    "productCode": "00001",
    "productType": "Food",
    "sellerDetails": [
      {
        "sellerName": "Cosco",
        "sellerCountry": "UK"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "productCode": "00002",
    "productType": "Clothing"
  }
]
';
DECLARE @json2 varchar(max) = '[
  {
    "productCode": "00001",
    "productType": "Food",
    "sellerDetails": [
      {
        "sellerName": "Cosco",
        "sellerCountry": "UK"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "productCode": "00002",
    "productType": "Clothing"
  },
  {
    "productCode": "00003",
    "productType": "Toy",
    "sellerDetails": [
      {
        "sellerName": "Cosco",
        "sellerCountry": "AUS",
        "sellerState": "VIC"
      }
    ]
  }
]
';
```

Comment: `OUTER APPLY OPENJSON (product.sellerDetails)` that way you get the rows without that whole property

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @Charlieface, that is what I'm doing.

Comment: `OUTER` not `CROSS`

Comment: You're absolutely right... sorry its late at night here ;)

Comment: Thank you Chris, there are so much knowledge in your detailed solution. I like SQL fiddle tool as well. I actually need to use ADF to implement solution, i didn't ask my question properly. That's fine, I got directions with what I need to do.